# How to display the next variable on a certain date

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables, date

I'm learning PHP and wondering is it possible to use the for statement to run an automated function.  I understand how variables and arrays work, but I just can't figure this one out.

Say I have a basketball schedule and I want to show the date of the next game, after the date of the most recent game; so if there's a game on the 3rd, on the 4th I would want the next game slot to show that the next game is on the 5th, the next game date.  I could create the games in the array but I don't seem to get how to call the right game on the right day.

Some direction would be helpful.

Comment: provide the print_r of your array so that I can answer it understand it properly.

Comment: Hmm here's a sample of what I was using. As you can see I'm trying to output the date, such as Nov 28th, then compare it to today's date. but i guess you cannot compare those?

$schedule = array(
 date("M j", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 2)), //Dec 2
 date("M j", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 13)), //Dec 13
);

 foreach($schedule as $date);
 
 // Get today's date (ex. Sep 10)
 $today = date('M j');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be **easily** done using timestamp, timestamp is a long number of seconds from Jan 1970, so if you can convert your date to timestamp you can easily compare it with other date timestamps. PHP has a function strtotime() which is use to convert any string date to its appropriate timestamp number,  here is a example

```
<?php
$schedule = array( strtotime('25 Nov 2012'),strtotime('2 Dec 2012'), strtotime('5 Dec 2012')); 
print_r($schedule);//will print timestamp numbers
$today  = time();// current timestamp

echo '<br>Next Game dates are :';
foreach($schedule as $date) {
  if($date > $today) {
     echo date('d M Y', $date);
     break;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Im glad that this does work, but my ultimate goal is to only return the closest element...one value. this returns all values > $time. So with the the elements in my array currently Dec 2 would be the next value.  I've played around with the next($schedule) but im still not getting the results.

should I use UNSET combined with an iterator?

Comment: Excellent. The "break" helped. Thanks a mil.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the key is how you store the day that a game is. I might do something like this:

```
$gamedays=array(1353734304, 1353725704);//these are timestamps of the game days
$time=time();
asort($time);
foreach($gamedays as $day){
    if($time>$day){
        $nextgame=next($gamedays);
    }
}
```

$nextgame will now be the timestamp of the next game.

Comment: im trying to output as "Jan 31" not as a timestamp. the array below is a sample of the schedule.  I've tried to compare date to today, then echo the result. but i'm guessing that's not possible if im using mktime and the date function?

    $schedule = array(
 date("M j", mktime(0, 0, 0, 01, 31)), //Jan 31
 date("M j", mktime(0, 0, 0, 02, 02)), //Feb 2   
 date("M j", mktime(0, 0, 0, 02, 07)), //Feb 7   
);
foreach($schedule as $date);
$today = date('M j');

Comment: date() supports an optional parameter timestamp. so you'd just do date`('format',$nextgame);` pankajs solution is better for your array thought